# Regex matching for only one value in a set of several possible strings, but not multiple strings in that set

Tags: regex

I want a regex that matches strings containing only instances of w, x, y, or z, **but not** any combinations of w, x, y, and z. "w ... w" is allowed, but not "w ... x" or "y ... y ... w".

I have tested the following on a few regex testing sites, but am trying to cut the length of the expression. Does anyone know how to express this more concisely?

```
(^(?!.*(x|y|z)).*(w))|(^(?!.*(w|y|z)).*(x))|(^(?!.*(w|x|z)).*(y))|(^(?!.*(w|y|x)).*(z))
```

Comment: So the string can only have one of any of the letters, and sometimes two `W`s?

Comment: Those are just examples. The strings can contain w any number of times, but not if x, y, or z are also present. The same goes for all these letters.

Comment: So any letter (quantity unimportant), so long as the others are not there?

Comment: Yes, exactly (also they must be bound by whitespace, if that matters)

Comment: Your usual perl regex, basically

Comment: Would something like this work? `^([wxyz])\1*$`

Comment: that seems to do the trick! How would I change it if w, x, y, and z were words (like cat, dog, etc.)? + I need case insensitivity (?i) but am not sure where to assign it

Comment: also @MichaelGao : I need it to match for things containing w, x, y, or z but other letters/strings are permitted. yyy is allowed and so is yyu but yyz is not.

Comment: This: [`^(?!.*(w|x|y|z)(?:(?!\1).)*(?!\1)(w|x|y|z)).*`](https://regex101.com/r/yQ6hQ8/1)? Or a bit simpler: [`^(?!.*(w|x|y|z).*(?!\1)(w|x|y|z)).*`](https://regex101.com/r/yQ6hQ8/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this matches for things that do not include w, x, y, or z as well. The presence of one of those letters is necessary for the match

Comment: Ok, `^(?!.*(w|x|y|z).*(?!\1)(w|x|y|z)).*(w|x|y|z)`? Or making it shorter in PCRE: [`^(?!.*(w|x|y|z).*(?!\1)(?1)).*(?1)`](https://regex101.com/r/yQ6hQ8/4)

Comment: perfect! Where do I insert the ?i to make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the negative lookahead, you can define the alternation capturing group and then check if there is one of the alternatives except the one matched before with a negative lookahead containing the backreference to the first capture group value. In PCRE regex, you can later re-use the Group 1 subpattern with `(?n)` syntax.

```
(?i)^(?!.*(w|x|y|z).*(?!\1)(?1)).*(?1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ6hQ8/4).

The `(?i)` will make it case insensitive.

Details:

- `(?i)` - the case-insensitive modifier
- `^` - start of string (line if `/m` modifier is used)
- `(?!.*(w|x|y|z).*(?!\1)(?1))` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if there is `w`, `x`, `y` or `z` somewhere in the string that are followed with one of these values but that is not the same as captured into Group 1
- `.*` - match and consume 0+ characters other than a newline (or if `/s` modifier is used, including a newline)
- `(?1)` - recurse the subpattern used in Group 1 (so, it is just the same as writing `(w|x|y|z)`).

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest way to do it `^(?=.*([wxyz]))(?:[^wxyz]|\1)+$`

```
 ^                    # BOS
 (?=
      .*                   # Lookahead to find
      ( [wxyz] )           # (1), Either w,x,y or z
 )
 (?:                  # Consume the string
      [^wxyz]              # Not w,x,y or z
   |                     # or,
      \1                   # Only the captured w,x,y or z allowd
 )+
 $                    # EOS
```

---

Here is a comparison of the other regex and this one.

Sample

```
zzzzzsadfbzzzzzzz
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   (?i)^(?!.*(w|x|y|z).*(?!\1)(?1)).*(?1)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    2.37 s,   2369.05 ms,   2369051 µs


Regex2:   ^(?=.*([wxyz]))(?:[^wxyz]|\1)+$
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.20 s,   204.42 ms,   204418 µs
```

If I were you, I'd use the more performant one.
Stay away from unnecessary complexity in assertions.

---

Even faster `^(?=.*([wxyz]))[^wxyz]*(?:\1[^wxyz]*)+$` using un-rolled loop.
Same with multiline `(?m)^(?=.*([wxyz]))[^wxyz\r\n]*(?:\1[^wxyz\r\n]*)+$`

Answer (score 0):

You could also avoid the instances using negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!(?:.*?(?:w.*[xyz]|x.*[yzw]|y.*[wxz]|z.*[wxy]).*|[^wxyz]+))(.*)$/gi
```

[DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/nQ1rM1/3)